# Cross Domain Request display data results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, cross-domain

I have test code for WordPress here.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var link = 'http://000.00.00.00/cgi-bin/test.cgi';
$("#sub").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST', 
        url: link,
        crossDomain: true,
        crossOrigin: true,
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }, 
        error: function(e) {
            console.log("Error: " + e);
        },
    });
});
```

the request seems fine because when i view my chrome network > headers tab status code is OK but the problem is that there is no data. I should have a working output like this..

`{ "loyalty" : { "status" : { "rows" : "1", "sql" : "success", "result" : "ok" }, "data" : [ { "card_number" : "1410104000350018" , "card_type" : "BEAUTY ADDICT" , "first_name" : "TINA" , "middle_initial" : "M" , "last_name" : "LIM" } ] } }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSONP` to get data from other domain than your javascript host, which is something like blow:

`$("#sub").click(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        url: link,
        dataType:'jsonp',
        jsonp:'callback',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }, 
        error: function(e) {
            console.log("Error: " + e);
        },
    });`

and because `JSONP` transmit data through `GET`, so In your server side code you need retrieve data from `$_GET` like this(if you use PHP):

`$your_param = $_GET['your_param'];
    $callBack = $_GET['callback'];
    //do something .....and get $result
    echo($callBack . '(' .json_encode($result) . ')');`

Comment: Hi thanks for fast response.. Can you tell me where to put your code in wordpress?     $your_param = $_GET['your_param'];
    $callBack = $_GET['callback'];
    //do something .....and get $result
    echo($callBack . '(' .json_encode($result) . ')');

Comment: Sorry I am very new in wordpress... should i create a new php file?

Comment: I don't use WordPress, so I don't know the exact place to write PHP code, but I think your link should point to a php file other than test.cgi, and write server side code in that php file.

Comment: Yeah, you need create a php file

Comment: Actually i dont have access in that url.. it was sent to me thru email an according to them, i can access the data via JSON or HTTP request.. And now i dont have a reply from them after asking. I tried JSONP and it gives me a query string something like... callback: jquery//and numbers etc... and in my error function it gave me an error result saying cant allow request something like that.. but when using JSON error function gives me an [Object, object] results

Comment: the link they have given has a cgi extension how can i parse the result of that extension?

Comment: callback: jquery//and numbers etc... is generated by Jquery automatically when use jsonp type, and it is corresponding to $callBack = $_GET['callback'].  If you want get data from other domain , you really need their cooperation who sent you that link.